# Cluster data based on similarity, but split by one feature (Python, R)

Tags: clustering, random-forest, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering

Is there a way to do unsupervised clustering based on similarity (like all other methods), but create clusters by splitting on just one (or specific) features? For example, I have customer data with lots of features, but I want to find the best clustering of data by segmenting the data on specific bands of customer revenue like [\$100, \$1500, \$10000], etc.

I just want to make sure to compare apples to apples in the best possible way. I'm currently thinking a combination of hierarchical clustering (if there's multiple columns) and Random Forest (to split based on specific predictors). I've looked into Unsupervised Random Forest but it seems to just find a best way to cluster data based on similarity by transforming it, and not give **how**, or which columns they used to split the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you formulate this as an optimization problem, you can run it through some optimization solver.

I.e. you would define your model with two thresholds t1 < t2 to partition your data into three clusters on your splitting attribute, and the optimization objective is to maximize the average pairwise similarity to all other members of the same partition.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Do you think this would work via Linear Programming, or it'd require some other form? Asking since I only really know LP. Thanks

Comment: I don't use optimizers, so I can't give you recommendations. Since you know LP, you already know more than I do.